# OSC packet implementation in win 32

Tags: winapi, packet, osc

Need help regarding OSC packet implementation in win 32 in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [oscpack](http://code.google.com/p/oscpack/) with c++. It is portable source code and I use it with win32/MacOSX/Linux.